# HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error - Deploying Sample Tomcat Web Applications

Tags: mysql, sql-server, http, tomcat, web-applications

[click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wUYB.png)

I am trying to open a webapps-WAR file in my browser with Tomcat. I am getting an HTTP 500 error as shown in screen shot. Do I need to upgrade SQL? I have version 5.7.22.

Error: client does not support authentication protocol requested by server. Consider upgrading SQL

Comment: Provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your MySQL Connector/J.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/